# Remove Line breaks from HTML string before inserting it into Excel Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, row, line-breaks

Im using Microsoft Visual Studio to extract data from a database into excel.  The data in the database field looks as follows:

```
RISK TITLE &amp; DESC.:this is a test to see if the data disappears. <br /> <ol> <li>mvkf</li> <li>fmjdk </li> </ol> kfhjl<br /> <ul> <li>jfidj </li> <li>fjdilfjwkl </li> </ul> fnhdjkfhkd<br /> <a href=http://islhnweb/ target=_blank>fhsdklfjsd<br /> </a>jdfkls
```

When i extract the data into excel each line of text is wrritten into a seperate row as follows:

Row 6   :  RISK TITLE & DESC.:this is a test to see if the data disappears.
Row 7   :
Row 8   :   1. mvkf
Row 9   :   2. fmjdk
Row 10  :
Row 11  :  kfhji
Row 12  :
Row 13  :  jfidj
Row 14  :  fjdilfjwkl
Row 15  :
Row 16  :  fnhdjkfhkd
Row 17  :  (link of)fhsdkfjsd
Row 18  :  (link of) jdfkls

I need to have the whole lot of the data in one cell in 1 row, not over multiple rows.

My code is:

```
case "longtext":
    tCell.Text = RLB(datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString());
    tCell.Width = 500;
    break;
```

Next part is as follows:

```
    protected string RLB(string strHTML)
    {
       StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
       HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(strHTML, myWriter);
       string strResult = myWriter.ToString();
       return strResult;
    }
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems you are asking for HTML to plain text converter (not just line breaks removal). Is it true?

Comment: they want to, if possible, have the data all in one cell, but still keep the bullet points, numbered lists and hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
tCell.Text = RLB(datarow[defrow["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString()).Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, String.Empty);
```

If it does not solve your problem, try to remove (by adding more .Replace() methods) other escape sequences, like:
\f (Formfeed);
\r (Carriage return);
\v (Vertical tab).

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it but this did not fix my issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce your issue on my PC; try some additional technique I described in my extended answer. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<br />` elements would probably go a fair ways toward fixing this. The `<ol>` elements seem to be causing the remaining problems, so those might need to be sacrificed, although since Excel does have in-cell formatting they can probably be edited back in with a bit of work after the insertion.